# What do you call a shot showing what's happening inside a body?

Tags: word-request

Sometimes, we see often see images showing a sagittal cut of the head to allow people to see the inside of the head. The issue is that there are no term for videos or segments of a video showing the sagittal cut of the head or the inside of the head to show how a tube inserted in the mouth goes inside the mouth and inside the esophagus. Is there a word specific for it, because I can't think of a short idiomatic way of saying it?

For example:

> The ____ showed the tube go inside the mouth and down his throat.

Comment: I don't know if there's a special word for that, but you could always say: _The video showed a sagittal view of the tube going inside the mouth and down his throat._

Comment: In Aboriginal art it's called x-ray style  http://www.xray-art.com/x-ray-style-art-in-australia/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A traditional term for views representing the interior 'surface' revealed by a plane transecting a three-dimensional is *(cross-)**section***; usually what is shown is an orthogonal section, although perspective or isometric views are also encountered. The section will be specified by the name of the transecting plane: a sagittal, coronal or transverse section in anatomy, a horizontal or vertical section in architecture, &c.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a term specific to medicine or anatomy, but the term [cross section](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/cross-section) is often used in situations where there is either a physical or virtual cut through an object either at right angles to or along some major axis.

If you're talking specifically about a picture or video, whether it's a drawing or the result of some imaging technology, you could call it a **cross-sectional view**.  This term is very commonly used in engineering, but [here is an example](https://www.gettyimages.ca/detail/illustration/nose-mouth-and-throat-cross-section-lateral-royalty-free-illustration/604230177) of **cross-sectional view** being used to show exactly the interior of the mouth and throat that you're asking about.  You'll also see the term **sectional view** (without the "cross"), which means any slice through the object, whereas the **cross-sectional** adds the sense of being either along or perpendicular to some major axis.

If your audience is familiar with the term **sagittal**, then you could call it a **sagittal cross-sectional view**, where "cross-sectional" indicates the cut through the body, while "sagittal" indicates the specific orientation of that cut.

Answer (score 0):

In static diagrams, such as those used in anatomy books this is often called a 'cut-away" diagram. I am not sure if that term is used in videos, and I doubt that there is a specific term for this one particular view. If there is, I don't know it.

Comment: I think the term _cutaway_ is used for something else when it comes to [video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutaway_(filmmaking)).